# Pattern Matching Between Variables of Two data frames in R

Tags: regex, r

My problem is how to make pattern match between Variables in different data frames . Lets say i have:

```
Df1$PrimaryCity<-C("Drew","Parchman","ALEXENDRIA","SAN JOSE") and
Df2$DESCRIPTION<-C("DUNKIN #XXXXXX     Q35   ALEXANDRIA   VA", "amazon.com/// xxx-ndnd SAN JOSE CA")
```

If we observe carefully the Primary City has `"ALEXENDRIA"` and `"SAN JOSE"` which matches with the Target pattern(DESCRIPTION). 
Procd1: I applied pmatch for the partial matching but it does not giving me the correct match.
Procd2: I applied a for loop on Primary Cities and search with a Pattern  in Description it is working .But my problem is the problem works(For loop) for small data. Its fine for now. I need to handle large data of 700Million records . IS there any efficient approach other than for loop.

Comment: how about `\b(Drew|Parchman|ALEXANDRIA|SAN JOSE)\b` in one regex?

Comment: Hello user3678068, thanks for the answer. The approach you are suggesting works fine with less no of patterns.But my Primary cities has around 18000 patterns .It does not work for that.

Comment: `sapply(City, function(x) grep(x, DESC))` maybe?

Comment: bummer. but doesn't hurt to give one giant regex a try. I think depending on the regex implementation, string search like this could take sublinear time (probably better than using for loop).

Comment: @RichardScriven i tried that thing yesterday. But it does not work.

Comment: Weird.  It just worked for me.

Comment: `C` (as opposed to `c`) is _still_ not the function you think it is. Also, don't be surprised when `ALEXENDRIA` doesn't match `ALEXANDRIA`. Please carefully check your questions :)